# Load markers dynamically while the page is loading

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, maps

is it possible to initialise a google map and then load the pins dynamically on it?
What I would like is a map where....as soon as the data is available, its marker pops up.
I am on a situation where the data come quite slowely so...it would me nice to give a feedback showing this partial results while the rest of the data come.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Answer (score 0):

`is it possible to initialise a google map and then load the pins dynamically on it?` Yes, use [AJAX](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic11.htm) to load the markers (note, that link is to a page from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial, that API is deprecated, but the same concepts apply to the current v3 API).

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look at it and let you know if I have problems :)